# Bad request with RestTemplate -> postForObject (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring-resttemplate

I'm experiencing some troubles with a simple matter.

I'm trying to send a request to other REST service

```
//getting restTemplate from RestTemplateBuilder.build()
//endpoint and rest of variables came in properties

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("app", app);
map.put("username", username);
map.put("password", password);
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

String token = restTemplate.postForObject(loginEndpoint, headers, String.class, map);
```

And I recive:

```
Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
```

The weird thing, when I use a simple CURL call and works smooth.

Already checked the variables and endpoint, and it's correct.

Comment: What does your endpoint expect?

Comment: Basically:

{{authUrl}}?app={{app}}&password={{password}}&username={{user}}

Just 3 params and I get a String as respose.

Comment: Does your loginEndpoint have the appropriate placeholders?

Comment: I don't know what you mind. It's use just expecting 3 parameters and no body

Whit this curl works

curl --location --request POST '[END_POINT]?app=[APP]&password=[PASSWORD]&username=[USERNAME]' \ --data-raw ''

Comment: That map argument you passed to postForObject is meant to be used to fill in the placeholders in your uri string.

Comment: Making the switch, it works properly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this case, endpoint must have appropiate placeholders on end point url.

I made this method to do it easy:

```
private String placeHolders(Map<String, String> values){
    String response = "?";
    boolean first = true;
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry:values.entrySet()){
        if(first){
            first = false;
        }else{
            response+="&";
        }
        response+=entry.getKey()+"="+entry.getValue();
    }
    return response;
}
```

And the call now Is:

```
String token = restTemplate.postForObject(loginEndpoint+placeHolders, headers, String.class, map);
```

Comment: Please use Spring's `UriComponentsBuilder` to generate URI the right way.